# vim8: Win8.1, netrw using scp, write fails with E382: Cannot write, 'buftype' option is set

Tags: windows, vim, netrw

This is the first time I am using the netrw plugin, I am able to open files on remote server using

```
:e scp://username@ipaddress//path/to/folder/
```

followed by selecting the correct file and opening it.

After I finish editing it when I try to write back the changes I get the E382: error specified in the title.

## Things tried so far.

- The default plugin used to fail without any warning.
- Downloaded and installed the latest plugin from the authors page after which I started seeing the *E382 error.
- Removed the 32 bit gvim and installed the 64 bit version.
- set scp path to use pscp v 0.69
- Added the following lines to _vimrc

`let g:netrw_cygwin =0
let g:netew_use_nt_rcp=0
let g:netrw_scp_cmd = "\"E:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\pscp.exe\" -pw password123"`